# How can I transform this statement into a ternary?

Tags: java, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I am trying to turn a simple if/else statement into a ternary for practice and I'm having trouble. From what I understand, the logic is:

```
condition ? (action to take if condition is true) : (action if false);
```

My condition is `if(result == 8)`.

I've already tried:

```
result == 8 ? return true : return false;
```

and

```
result = 8 ? return true : return false;
```

Here's my code, the end of which I would like to convert

```
public boolean sum28(int[] nums) {

    int result = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {
        if(nums[i] == 2) {
            result+=2;
        }
    }
    if(result == 8) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I'm getting a type mismatch: cannot convert from int to boolean when I use only 1 equals sign, and getting a invalid token "==" when using two.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct syntax would be

```
return (result == 8) ? true : false;
```

but here you can just

```
return result == 8;
```

Comment: No need for those parens (though of course you may prefer them as a matter of style).

Answer (score 8):

> ```
> condition ? (action to take if condition is true) : (action if false);
> ```

The ternary operator isn't a full blown replacement for `if`/`else`. The two alternatives must be expressions, not statements. Better to think of it as:

```
condition ? (result if true) : (result if false)
```

The result of the operator is a value which can then be used in a larger statement. To use it in a `return` statement you need to put the `return` up front.

```
return result == 8 ? true : false;
```

Note that this is more simply written without the ternary operator.

```
return result == 8;
```

Comment: Excellent opening description, pointing out where the OP's understanding went awry.

Answer (score 6):

> I've already tried: result == 8 ? return true : return false;

You're not too far off. `==` results in a boolean, so you just want:

```
return result == 8;
```

That works because you already have the value (`true` or `false`) that you want to return; it's the result of `result == 8`.

Similarly, if your original were the other way around (`if (result == 8) { return false; } else { return true; }`), you'd use `!=`:

```
// If you wanted the opposite
return result != 8;
```

---

In the more general case, suppose you wanted to return `"A"` if `result == 8` and `"B"` otherwise. You'd do that like this:

```
// If you wanted to return "A" (if result == 8) or "B" (if not)
return result == 8 ? "A" : "B";
```